# how to repalce the bigger index of upper triangular matrix by lower index.and according to that want to change matrix label number. MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

I m having a vector of detected speaker change point`

```
SCP=[10 25 43];
```

from this i made a mtrix

```
seg_result=
          start-time   end-time
speaker1  1            10
speaker2  10           25
speaker3  25           43
speaker4  43           end-time of audio wav(for ex: 50)
```

after this i did the homogeneous speaker clustering.result of which is the matrix in which lower triangular matrix will always be zero,matrix is as follows,

```
cluster_result=

0   -567   345   324
0     0    567   768
0     0     0    534
0     0     0     0
```

then i detected the negatives number in matrix.

```
for i=2:length(cluster_result)
    for j=(i+1):length(cluster_result)
        if cluster_result(i,j)<0
```

here the value at cluster_result(i,j),means distance value between speaker(i) and speaker(j),for ex:cluster_result(1,2) means distance value between speaker1 and speaker2.
.now ones I get the negative numbers from cluster_result,i need following

1) the index of this negative numbers.
2) then I want to replace the j by i,means I want speaker2 should become speaker1.and want to create(or u can say replace previous seg_result matrix)  as follow

```
seg_result=
          start-time   end-time
speaker1  1            10
speaker1  10           25
speaker3  25           43
speaker4  43           end-time of audio wavfile(for ex: 50)
```

your help will be appreciated heartily...

Comment: please describe your problem more clearly, how is your desired result supposed to look like?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `find()` in the following way:

```
negatives= cluster_result<0; % Logical operation, returns a binary matrix with 1 where the expression is true/ exactly equivalent to your loop.
```

Output:

```
negatives=
     0     1     0     0
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
```

Then use `find()` with two outputs to get the indexes of the non-zero elements of your binary matrix:

```
[ii,jj]=find(negatives); if you use only one output, you'll get a linear index
```

Output:

```
ii =

     1

jj =

     2
```

Now that you have your indexes `ii` and `jj` you can replace and rearange them as it pleases you.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thankx for your reply.this is fine.I can replace jj by ii also.but after this, see the first seg_result matrix (in my asked question) that should become like the last seg_result matrix (given in my asked question)...there speaker2 get replaced by speaker1...

Comment: That depends on how you generate your matrix. Can you edit your question explaining how 'seg_result' looks like?